# Save InkManager images to byte array

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm new to win8 app programming but has been assigned to write a windows store app to capture customers' signature and save it to SQL Server. After some research I found a great tutorial
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416878/Metro-Paint which shows how to draw and save the image locally. My question is how do I use the InkManager class in the tutorial to save the image to byte arrays so that I can save the image to SQLServer? Thanks!

```
    private async void btnSaveWritingAsImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyInkManager.GetStrokes().Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker SavePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
                SavePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
                SavePicker.DefaultFileExtension = ".png";
                SavePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("PNG", new string[] { ".png" });
                SavePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPG", new string[] { ".jpg" });
                StorageFile filesave = await SavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
                IOutputStream ab = await filesave.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
                if (ab != null)
                    await MyInkManager.SaveAsync(ab);
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                var MsgDlg = new MessageDialog("Only handwriting can be saved as image.", "Error while saving");
                MsgDlg.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var MsgDlg = new MessageDialog("Only handwriting can be saved as image.", "Error while saving");
            await MsgDlg.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add: (IBuffer.ToArray() is defined in WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions)

using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

then just do:

```
var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(image);//replace ab instead of image
var bytes = buffer.ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi Suganthi, thanks for the reply, however I do not want the image to save locally, instead I would like the picture in the paint board to be convert to byte array right after user click the save button. Can you help me modify the code please?